# How to use Requests POST method to get the search result from website?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get the output of the website search result, i am using requests post method to do it. Below you can see the FORM and INPUT htmls from the url. I need to get each search result in input of form.

I have tried the code below ***but it returns nothing***

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# FORM from website
# <form name="form1" method="post" action="payerOrVoenChecker.jsp">

# INPUT from the website
# <input type="text" name="voen" size="38" style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: groove;
# BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: groove; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: groove; BORDER-TOP-STYLE: groove; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY:
# Tahoma, Arial; FONT-SIZE: 12px" value="">

request_headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Host': 'www.e-taxes.gov.az',
    'Origin': 'https://www.e-taxes.gov.az',
    'Referer': 'https://www.e-taxes.gov.az/ebyn/payerOrVoenChecker.jsp',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'YOUR USER AGENT',
}

voens = {2000460031,
         1000877741,
         1000877741,
         1500403661,
         1000877741,
         3000489411,
         1000877741,
         1802142932,
         }

tip = ['L',
       'P',
       ]

form_data = {
    'tip': tip,
    'voenOrName': 'V',
    'voen': voens,
    'name': '',
    'submit': '  Yoxla   ',
}


url = 'https://www.e-taxes.gov.az/ebyn/payerOrVoenChecker.jsp'

for voen in voens:
    form_data['voen'] = voen
    form_data['tip'] = tip
    response = requests.post(url, data=form_data, headers=request_headers)
    s = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
    sContent = s.findAll('table', {'class': 'com'})[0].findAll('tr', recursive=False)[1]
    outcome = sContent.get_text().strip()
    # .find("tr", recursive=False)
    print(outcome)
```

Expected result will be in a table form, i am adding the screenshot of before and after search in website, ***the highlighted are is the table i need to get***

[image]
[image]

Comment: The code I provided in my answer was for demonstration. Change the `'YOUR USER AGENT'` part to your own user agent. Copy it from the network tab of your browser's developer tools. Otherwise, it'll probably not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the other items that are to be sent in the body of the `POST` request.

Try this:

```
request_headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Host': 'www.e-taxes.gov.az',
    'Origin': 'https://www.e-taxes.gov.az',
    'Referer': 'https://www.e-taxes.gov.az/ebyn/payerOrVoenChecker.jsp',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'YOUR USER AGENT',
}

form_data = {
    'tip': 'L',
    'voenOrName': 'V',
    'voen': '1700393071',
    'name': '',
    'submit': '  Yoxla   ',
}

response = requests.post(url, data=form_data, headers=request_headers)
```

The best way to figure these out is to switch to Network tab in the developer's tools in the browser. The shortcut in both Chrome and Firefox is F12.

- Once you open the Developer's Tools, go to Network Tab.
- Now, submit all the requests which you want to automate (e.g., in this case, clicking on Submit after filling in the ID).

It'll show you a list of all the requests that the browser is sending behind the scenes. Click on the one that matches your URL.

A pane will open on the right that shows what method (GET / POST) was used, what headers were passed in the request, what data was sent (in case of POST), etc.

All I did was paste the request headers and form data from that tab.

[image: inspecting network tab]

Comment: that worked but can i prettify it beacuse it return everything (whole html of page) but i need only the answer

Comment: and also can i use multiple ('voen': xxxx) id numbers to search

Comment: @ValiValizada for multiple IDs, you'll have to loop over all the IDs and then send each of them in a separate POST request. As for pretty printing the HTML response, try `print(soup.prettify())`.

Comment: i have updated the question for multiple IDs, but it returns same thing

Comment: @ValiValizada inside the for loop, assign the ID to 'voen' key of 'form_data', like this: `form_data['voen'] = voen`. You are not supposed to pass a list in the POST request like that.

Comment: in the output i have two "tr" and i need the second "tr"  so i am using this line `sContent = s.findAll("table", {"class": "com"}).find("tr", recursive=False)[1]` but it returns error message

Comment: @ValiValizada Go through [this BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). `s.findAll` returns a list of items. You're using the `find` method on that list, which is the first error. On the other hand, `first` fetches only the first tag, which is not a list and hence the `[1]` at the end will fail too. What you're probably looking for is `s.findAll('table', {'class': 'com'})[0].findAll('tr', recursive=False)[1]`.

Comment: thank it works and i updated the code you can see in the question but the problem is  `sContent = s.findAll('table', {'class': 'com'})[0].findAll('tr', recursive=False)[1]
IndexError: list index out of range` why it returns it?

Comment: i have another problem that i updated in the question the site has to radio bar that one is for corporate and another one for individuals. so i have created an array named "tip" and have values L for corporate and P for individual and include it form_data but it is not working. Code supposed to check if the voen is not in the tip of P then have to check if it is in the L. i hope you get what i mean \